# How to make tab bar lay over content in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want my tab bar to be translucent and blur the content behind it, but when I set its color to clear color it turns black instead. Currently I have my tab bar created programmatically in the app delegate. I made a class function called `getTabBarController` and configured my tab bar in there, and I call it in app delegate to return the tab bar. At last, I write 
`let vc = TabBarInitializer.getTabBarController()
 self.window!.rootViewController = vc`. Am I creating my tab bar incorrectly? How do I make the tab bar be on top of my content so that the translucent effect works?

Answer (score 0):

You have place view or content behind tabbar which you have to show instead of black.

So when tab transparent, view behind the tabbar become visible.

Comment: I do have content behind the tab bar, but the tab bar turns black when I set its background color to clear color or background image to a transparent image.